# Manually resizing image in CommCare while maintaining auto-resize on remaining images

Tags: commcare

In Android Settings I configured images to be auto-resized to half size. This works for all but one of my images, which I would like to be full-sized. Is it possible to manually adjust the sizing of specific images while maintaining auto-resizing on the rest of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible - auto-resize will be absolute for each image when set. I recommend looking into the [manual image resizing tool](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Image+Sizing+with+Multiple+Android+Device+Models) if this is hard requirement.